# How to Run Ajax request automatically after a specific time?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an Ajax function (ajaxRequest) that I want to run automatically after some specific time (say 5 sec) without any user-prompt or warning . How can i do this? (I looked in the following links but found no solution )

[jQuery: How to make an AJAX request and continue without waiting for request to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783227/jquery-how-to-make-an-ajax-request-and-continue-without-waiting-for-request-to)

[How do I run ajax request in background continuously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959866/how-do-i-run-ajax-request-in-background-continuously)

[How to run ajax call in background after some particulate time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604656/how-to-run-ajax-call-in-background-after-some-particulate-time)

[How to run execute page in background using ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955269/how-to-run-execute-page-in-background-using-ajax)

```
//My Code
//ajaxRequest Script..

<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxRequest(map){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'json_data.php', true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    setMarkers(map,myArr);
}
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
var lat=51.508742;
var lng=-0.140850;
var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 5};
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas,mapOptions);

ajaxRequest(map);                                   //Called ajaxRequest

}
</script>
```

Comment: Google setTimeout()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello this is solution for the automatically send the ajax request

Just put your function like this.

```
function myMap() {
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
var lat=51.508742;
var lng=-0.140850;
var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 5};
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas,mapOptions);                     
setInterval(function()
    {
      ajaxRequest(map);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks Everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want execute your code once you can use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), if you want execute your code every x seconds you can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    //The code you want to execute after 5 seconds
}, 5000);
//OR
setInterval(function() {
    //The code you want to execute every 5 seconds  
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

after run `mymap()` function the ajax request trigger in `5sec`.

if You need ajax run at the time page load apply like this:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {ajaxRequest(map);},5000);
</script>
```

directly place with in a `script`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxRequest(map){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'json_data.php', true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    setMarkers(map,myArr);
}
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
var lat=51.508742;
var lng=-0.140850;
var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 5};
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas,mapOptions);

setTimeout(function() {ajaxRequest(map);},5000);    //Called ajaxRequest

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute the ajax call after every 5 seconds, try following:
`setInterval (function() { 
  ajaxRequest(map);
}, 5000);`

Answer (score 1):

Use [setTimeout(fn, time)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to call the function once after a specified time(ms) or use [setIntreval(fn, time)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to call the function repeatedly for a specified time

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```js
setTimeout(function() {
//post your ajax code here
}, 1000);
```

For more check here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp